# Ajax open in new tab

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have ajax website and when i click a link to open in new tab it takes me to home is there any library or helper for ajax where open in new tab work ?

Comment: you can use <a href="" target="_blank">

Comment: no it will open auto but i want to use browser functionality right click on the link and open it new tab and it will exactly land me on that page not take me to home page

Comment: Sounds like you need a "history" plugin. This will simply change your URL to `www.test.com#!location/to/page.html` or similar. For example: http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/

Answer (score 0):

you can add target="_blank" in your  tag.
it will direct to required page in new tab

Comment: Please read the comments under the question, espacially Sundas' answer to tomexsans' comment.